# Randomatically select from a json discord.py

Tags: json, discord.py

I'm trying to create a command where a random meme is shown from a `json`.
Unfortunately I can't do it ... I can do it using `random.choice` normally but since I'm a lazy person to update the code I always created a command that would allow me to add them in a json. So I have to be able to randomly extract the main key of my json. How could I do?

code:

```py
@client.command(aliases=["Meme","MEME"])
async def meme(ctx):
    await ctx.message.delete()
    meme_data_dict = meme_data.json
    url = random.choice(list(meme_data_dict.keys))
    print(url)
    author = meme_data_dict[url]["autore"]
    title = meme_data_dict[url]["titolo"]
    channel = client.get_channel(638016878589116416)
    if ctx.channel.id == channel.id:
        embed = discord.Embed(
            title=f'{title}',
            color=0x003399
        )
        embed.set_author(name=f'fatto da {author}')
        embed.set_footer(text=f'Richiesto da {ctx.author.name}')
        embed.set_image(url=url)
        await ctx.send(embed=embed)
    else:
        embed = discord.Embed(
            color=0xa61022
        )
        embed.set_author(
            name=f"Per questo comando devi usare {channel.name}!",
        )
        await ctx.send(embed=embed, delete_after=10.0)
        return
```

Json (your name is meme_data.json):

```json
{"https://cdn.discordapp.com/avatars/491769129318088714/f23fd300d377ab133db1d6ac7db5d10b.webp?size=1024": {"autore": "10", "titolo": "sesso pazzoide"}, "https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/638016878589116416/839977460384923659/soviet_soldier_2.jpg": {"autore": "pene", "titolo": "ciaociao"}}
```

This is how my json is active:

```py
@client.event
async def on_ready():
    global meme_data
    try:
        with open('meme_data.json') as f:
            meme_data = json.load(f)
    except FileNotFoundError:
        print("Impossibile caricare meme_data.json")
        meme_data = {}
```

error:

```
Ignoring exception in command meme:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\PC GIUSEPPE\PycharmProjects\LMIIBot Development\venv\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 85, in wrapped
    ret = await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:/Users/PC GIUSEPPE/PycharmProjects/LMIIBot Development/LMIIBot Development.py", line 2235, in meme
    meme_data_dict = meme_data.json
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'json'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\PC GIUSEPPE\PycharmProjects\LMIIBot Development\venv\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\bot.py", line 903, in invoke
    await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
  File "C:\Users\PC GIUSEPPE\PycharmProjects\LMIIBot Development\venv\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 859, in invoke
    await injected(*ctx.args, **ctx.kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\PC GIUSEPPE\PycharmProjects\LMIIBot Development\venv\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 94, in wrapped
    raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'json'
```

Comment: Try renaming your variable `meme` to something like `meme_data`, because there is this function called `meme`. Also what exactly is your error?

Comment: i updated the post, my error is `discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'json'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get a random object of a dictionary (imported json file), you use `url = random.choice(list(meme_data_dict.keys))`. That in your code would be:

```py
@client.command(aliases=["Meme","MEME"])
async def meme(ctx):
    await ctx.message.delete()
    meme_data_dict = meme_data #you have to rename your variable meme, for example to meme_data, because there is already the function called meme
    url = random.choice(list(meme_data_dict.keys()))
    print(url)
    author = meme_data_dict[url]["autore"]
    title = meme_data_dict[url]["titolo"]
    #the rest of your code can stay the same
```

If this doesn't answer your question, clarify more what the problem is.

Comment: I have updated the post by clarifying (I hope) every point. I tried the code and now it gives me a different error (which I wrote in the post)

Comment: Ok, then I read your code wrong. You can simple remove `.json` after `meme_data_dict = meme_data` I updated my post now aswell @peppewarrior1

Comment: hi, I tried and now it gives me this error `: 'builtin_function_or_method' object is not iterable` when it comes up `url = random.choice(list(meme_data_dict.keys))`

Comment: My bad, there have to be `()` after `keys` @peppewarrior1